# JavaFX button binding exception

Tags: user-interface, button, javafx, binding

```
public class AccountOverviewController {

//declarations ...

@FXML
private Button undoButton;

@FXML
private Button redoButton;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    transactionsTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
            SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataValue -> dataValue.getValue()
            .getDateProperty());
    payeeColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataValue -> dataValue.getValue()
            .getPayeeProperty());
    categoryColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataValue -> dataValue.getValue()
            .getCategoryProperty());
    inflowColumn.setCellValueFactory(dataValue -> dataValue.getValue()
            .getInflowProperty());

    deleteButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(transactionsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));

    editButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(transactionsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()).isNotEqualTo(1));

    undoButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(commandRegistry.getCommandStack()));
    redoButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(commandRegistry.getUndoCommandStack()));
}

//handlers&setters ...
}
```

These two lines at the end are causing error. I want to disable buttons when the commands stacks are empty. I don't know why. For example same button disabling for Delete/Edit button works fine. Whole application without these two works perfectly fine.

Exception chain:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/simon/eclipse/java-neon-workspace/to2/lab2/cw3/bin/pl/edu/agh/iisg/to/javafx/cw3/view/AccountOverviewPane.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at pl.edu.agh.iisg.to.javafx.cw3.presenter.AccountPresenter.initRootLayout(AccountPresenter.java:35)
    at pl.edu.agh.iisg.to.javafx.cw3.Main.start(Main.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$106(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$119(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$117(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$118(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$450(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.edu.agh.iisg.to.javafx.cw3.view.AccountOverviewController.initialize(AccountOverviewController.java:97)
    ... 23 more
```

Both of stacks are declared like this in `CommandRegistry` class

```
private ObservableList<Command> commandStack = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

and getters are returning themselves naturally. What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Could you please add the full code for `AccountOverviewController`? Your trace says `NullPointerException`, are you sure `commandRegistry` is initialized?

Comment: So which line is line 97?

Comment: In this particular example it is this with `undoButoon.disablePrope...`. But everyone of them cause same exception chain. Here is whole [project](https://github.com/Sukiennik/JavaFX-Projects/tree/master/pl/edu/agh/iisg/to/javafx/cw3) and here [AccountOverviewController](http://pastebin.com/cvGRY5z5)

Comment: So presumably `undoButton` is null?

Comment: It seems like you're accessing `commandRegistry` without initializing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @beatngu13 But it is initialized inside `AccountPresenter` class as class variable (then when class is launched). This class is instantiated in `start()` method before using `commandRegistry`.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that `AccountOverviewController` has that (or another) instance, too. As I said before, you have to include the full sources of that class. Otherwise it's hard to tell what exactly went wrong.

Comment: @beatngu13 I gave link to github project above. I'm seriously unable to find the problem here.

Comment: My bad, didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your [project](https://github.com/Sukiennik/JavaFX-Projects), especially [`AccountOverviewController`](https://github.com/Sukiennik/JavaFX-Projects/blob/master/pl/edu/agh/iisg/to/javafx/cw3/view/AccountOverviewController.java) and [`AccountPresenter`](https://github.com/Sukiennik/JavaFX-Projects/blob/master/pl/edu/agh/iisg/to/javafx/cw3/presenter/AccountPresenter.java), I'd say you get that `NullPointerException` because the controller tries to access `commandRegistry` within `initialize()` *before* the class has an instance of `CommandRegistry`.

Have a look at lines 38 – 41 of `AccountPresenter`:

```
AccountOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setPresenter(this);
controller.setData(DataGenerator.generateAccountData());
controller.setCommandRegistry(commandRegistry);
```

You create your controller and set `commandRegistry` afterwards. But `initialize()` is invoked directely after calling the constructor of `AccountOverviewController` (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785417/javafx-fxml-controller-constructor-vs-initialize-method) question for details). At this time, `commandRegistry` is `null`.

One way to fix this is by moving the bindings into the setter:

```
public void setCommandRegistry(CommandRegistry commandRegistry) {
    this.commandRegistry = commandRegistry;

    undoButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(commandRegistry.getCommandStack()));
    redoButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(commandRegistry.getUndoCommandStack()));

    commandLogView.setItems(commandRegistry.getCommandStack());
    commandLogView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Command>() {
        protected void updateItem(Command item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText((item != null && !empty) ? item.getName() : null);
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. How then bindings work on `transactionsTable` if it also isn't initialized during calling controller yet. For example `editButton` or `deleteButton`.

Comment: @Saris Because all dependencies are already there. `editButton` and `deleteButton` need `transactionTable`. All of these fields are annotated with `@FXML`, which is invoked before. All you have to remeber is this execution order: 1. Constructor, 2. `@FXML`, 3. `initialize()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience.