# JavaFx call super method after super initialization

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, fxml, super

I have a class that implements Initializable.

```
public abstract class ExampleClass implements Initializable {

    public void ExampleClass() {
        // Load FXML
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Initialize stuff
    }

    public void afterInitialize() {
        // Do things that are reliant upon the FXML being loaded
    }
}
```

I then extend this abstract class:

```
public class ExampleSubclass extends ExampleClass {

    public ExampleSubclass() {
        super(/* real code has params */);
        this.afterInitialize(); // Problem here
    }
}
```

However when I call afterInitialize(), it behaves as though the FXML in the abstract class hasn't been loaded yet. This confuses me, as I call the super() constructor first, so I believe the FXML should have already been loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not calling `this.afterInitialize();` inside the `initialize(..,...);`? Only then you are soore that the FXML has been successfully loaded. Your question is interesting.

Comment: Typically that's what I'd do, but I need to pass parameters from `ExampleSubclass` to `afterInitialize()` (Probably should've specified that in the question, my bad)

Comment: Actually the answer provided here is excellent , i din't even knew about `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785707/387048), invocation of `initialize` method won't happen in the constructor, but after it. So when you call `afterInitialize` in subclass's constructor, it actually is called before `initialize`!

> In a few words: The constructor is called first, then any @FXML
>   annotated fields are populated, then initialize() is called...

So when `initialize` is called all FXML elements are already loaded and as others suggested, you can call `afterInitialize` inside `initialize` method but if you don't want to do that, you can use `@PostConstruct` annotation:

```
public abstract class ExampleClass implements Initializable {

    public void ExampleClass() {
        // Load FXML
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Initialize stuff
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterInitialize() {
        // Do things that are reliant upon the FXML being loaded
    }
}


public class ExampleSubclass extends ExampleClass {

    public ExampleSubclass() {
        super(/* real code has params */);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void afterInitialize() {
         super.afterInitialize();
        // other things
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be useful also ( http://zachxu.blogspot.gr/2016/09/java-annotation-postconstruct-and.html )

Comment: That definitely answered my question, thank-you! I didn't know about the @PostConstruct tag, so reading about that has been pretty helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it helped