# FXMLLoader initialization and SpringBoot - @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I have a question from a tutorial by **MVP Integrating Spring Boot with JavaFX**

GitHub: https://github.com/mvpjava

Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjeSOxi3uPg

where there is a public method named **initialization()** that I don't know how it is invoked after spring boot application starts up. I looked everywhere in the classes and fxml files that it could have a reference to it, and I found none.

I want to know how this method is invoked since I also want to do some initialization of JavaFX controls. I tried using @PostConstruct but this is wrong since all beans are created before any JavaFX controls are created thus I get null pointer exception.

I will be very grateful if someone will enlighten me on this matter.

here is the class at which the public method **initialization()** I mentioned.

```
@Component
public class ConsoleTabController {

    @FXML private TextArea missionOverviewText;
    @FXML private ListView<String> missionsList;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("stringPrintWriter")
    private PrintWriter stackTraceWriter;

    @Autowired MissionsService service;
    private TabPaneManger tabManager;

    public void initialize() {
        ObservableList<String> missions = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apollo", "Shuttle", "Skylab");
        missionsList.setItems(missions);
    }

    @FXML
    private void onMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        missionOverviewText.clear();
        final String selectedItem = missionsList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        missionOverviewText.positionCaret(0);
        missionOverviewText.appendText(getInfo(selectedItem));
    }

    @Autowired
    private void setTabManager(TabPaneManger tabManager){
        this.tabManager = tabManager;
    }

    public String getInfo(String selectedItem) {
        String missionInfo = null ;

        try {
            missionInfo = service.getMissionInfo(selectedItem); 
            getLog().appendText("Sucessfully retrieved mission info for " + selectedItem + "\n");
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace (stackTraceWriter);
            getLog().appendText(stackTraceWriter.toString() + "\n");
        }
        return missionInfo;
    }

    public TextArea getMissionOverviewText() {
        return missionOverviewText;
    }

    public ListView<String> getMissionsList() {
        return missionsList;
    }

    private TextArea getLog(){
        return tabManager.getVisualLog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010909/using-initialize-method-in-a-controller-in-fxml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `initialize()` method (which is what I think you mean) is invoked by the `FXMLLoader`. In general, for an `FXMLLoader`, the order of execution is:

1. `FXMLLoader` loads the FXML file and parses it
2. If the root element in the FXML file has a `fx:controller` attribute, it gets a reference to an instance of that class; it does this by passing the controller class to the `controllerFactory`, if one is set, or by calling the controller class's default constructor otherwise.
3. Any elements with `fx:id` attributes are injected into the controller fields with matching `@FXML` annotations
4. The `FXMLLoader` invokes the controller's `initialize()` method, if it has one.

In your case, I assume you are setting the controller factory of the `FXMLLoader` to delegate to the Spring application context, i.e. I assume you have something like

```
ApplicationContext appContext = ... ; // Spring bean factory
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(...);
loader.setControllerFactory(appContext::getBean);
Parent ui = loader.load();
```

This means that the controller instances will be created by passing the controller class to the Spring bean factory's `getBean(...)` method. So if the FXML file has `fx:controller="ConsoleTabController"`, the `FXMLLoader` essentially calls

```
Object controller = appContext.getBean(ConsoleTabController.class);
```

in step 2 above. The Spring application context creates a `ConsoleTabController` instance (assuming you have configured the controller bean as having prototype scope, which you should), injects any `@AutoWired`-annotated properties, calls any `@PostConstruct`-annotated methods, and then provides the controller to the `FXMLLoader`. So the overall order of execution when you use the Spring bean factory as the controller factory is

1. `FXMLLoader` loads the FXML file and parses it

   If the root element in the FXML file has a `fx:controller` attribute:

   1. The Spring bean factory creates an instance of the controller class

      The Spring bean factory injects any `@Autowired`-annotated properties into the controller instance

      The Spring bean factory invokes any `@PostConstruct`-annotated methods on the controller instance

      The controller instance is returned to the `FXMLLoader`

   Any elements with `fx:id` attributes are injected into the controller fields with matching `@FXML` annotations by the `FXMLLoader`

   The `FXMLLoader` invokes the controller's `initialize()` method, if it has one.

Note that there are essentially two different kind of injected fields, and two different kinds of "initialization" methods in this scenario. The "Spring injected fields", annotated `@Autowired` (or `@Inject`) are injected first, then the "Spring initialization methods" (annotated `@PostConstruct`) are invoked. After that, the "FXML injected fields" (annotated `@FXML`) are injected, and then the "FXML initialization method" (the one called `initialize()`) is invoked. You don't have any `@PostConstruct` methods in your sample code, but the one thing to be careful of is that those methods would be invoked *before* the `@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Now I know who is calling the initialize() method, it is the `FXMLLoader`. I tried to replicate the tutorial pattern into my project and that is where I stumbled, I forgot to include the fxml file its **controller  class** when I am testing that is why the `initialize()` method is never invoked. So I tried the `@PostConstruct` annotation instead and I got `NullPointerException` which you also explained and too how did i got such error.

Thank you very much for step by step explanation.