# javafx controller class creation

Tags: javafx

```
package Test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;


public class TestController implements Initializable {


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

I want to make Constructor in this TestController Class

Comment: What is stopping you? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I created an empty Constructor for you.

```
package Test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;


public class TestController implements Initializable {

    //Empty Constructor
    public TestController()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

Comment: What about "initialize" method?what is the difference between "TestController" and "initialize" method?.is "initialize" method also worked as a constructor?

Comment: @RafsanBabu Hello again, this specific question has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785417/javafx-fxml-controller-constructor-vs-initialize-method